# Issue with LSTM/GRU model acurracy in a protocol prediction implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I have a specific model to create.I will go into further details below

1. I have a wireshark cap file,from which i have generated a csv file of 1.4 rows(not the entire cap file but just a sample of it)
2. The information I want to use in my model is **Source,Destination,Protocol** columns and the **LSTM** model I implemented is supposed to understand relationship between Source/Destination/Protocol fields and **make prediction on the protocol field**.
3. Here come the problems...The protocols in the protocol field are **imbalanced** with around 1 million TCP and 200.000 UDP instances,whilst the rest is other protocols
4. The model i have created achieves 0.8-0.85 accuracy which is solely the TCP predictions

I have tried to adjust the **sequence length,epochs,batch size,take only a smaller portion of the dataset(which leads into worse predictions)**
I also tried to do some weight balancing on the protocols,the default_weight library makes the accuracy 0.3/0.4 for each protocol but due to the fact that the main protocol of the sample is the TCP ,the overall accuracy is 0.2

Any suggestions on what I could change to improve the accuracy for the undersampled protocols are most welcome!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Load and preprocess the data
data = pd.read_csv('paketa.csv')
data = data.dropna()
data = data[(data['Protocol'] != 'IPv6') & (data['Protocol'] != 'MPTCP')]
unique_classes = data['Protocol'].unique()
print("Unique Class Indices:", unique_classes)
# Extract subset of the data
#subset_start_index = 0
#subset_end_index = 200000
#subset_data = data.iloc[subset_start_index:subset_end_index]

# Preprocess categorical features using FeatureHasher
# Convert 'Source' and 'Destination' to lists of strings
source_strings = data['Source'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split('.')).values
destination_strings = data['Destination'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split('.')).values

hasher_source = FeatureHasher(n_features=10, input_type='string')
hashed_source = hasher_source.transform(source_strings)
hashed_destination = hasher_source.transform(destination_strings)

# One-hot encode the 'Protocol' feature
protocol_onehot = pd.get_dummies(data['Protocol'])

# Combine the preprocessed features
hashed_features_array = np.concatenate([hashed_source.toarray(), hashed_destination.toarray(), protocol_onehot], axis=1)

# Continue with the rest of your code
sequence_length = 10
sequences = []
targets = []

for i in range(len(hashed_features_array) - sequence_length):
    seq = hashed_features_array[i:i+sequence_length]
    target = data.iloc[i+sequence_length]['Protocol']
    sequences.append(seq)
    targets.append(target)

X = np.array(sequences)
y = np.array(targets)
print(X)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

# Convert target labels to numerical indices
unique_labels = np.unique(y)
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(unique_labels)
y_indices = np.array([label_encoder.transform([label])[0] for label in y])

# Convert target indices to one-hot encoded vectors
y_onehot = to_categorical(y_indices, num_classes=len(unique_labels))

# Build LSTM model
num_classes = len(unique_labels)
num_features = hashed_features_array.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(sequence_length, num_features)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Use TimeSeriesSplit for train-test split
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y_onehot[train_index], y_onehot[test_index]

    # Train the model without class weights
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

    # Evaluate the model
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print("Model Results:")
    print(f"Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}")
```

Comment: A code snippet showing what you're doing so far would help.

Comment: i edited the original post with the code i am currently using...
let me know if you see anything weird and wrong in there i am not familiar with python even more with DL...!
to make it more specific,source and destination fields are on the form of IP addresses, meaning 123.xxx.xx.xx and protocol field contains 9 different categories of Protocols,with a kinda big instances difference as i mentioned...

Comment: also the current presented code includes only the LSTM model since i decided to split them for the time being for resource reasons

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to notice. Although this won't likely solve your problem, it is too much text to comment on. First of all, are you sure the packet data is time-dependent?  When I think of network traffic, I'm not sure if packet `x+1` is determinable just from knowing where packets `0` to `x` were going. Just because there is a time variable, doesn't mean the problem is always time-dependent.
For the features, you can look into one-hot encoding, but it looks like it's only viable for the protocol feature. While one-hot encoding has its drawbacks, label encoding brings order into the feature, and you don't want that here. The protocol labeled 0 would be "smaller" than protocol 1, the mean of protocols 1 and 3 is protocol 2, and so on. IP addresses are also categorical data. I worked with IP address data once, and we used [feature hashing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html) for it. Not saying it is the only (or a generally good) way, but it brings a few pros with it.

Normally, you don't fit your encoder/scaler on the whole data, just on the training data. Label-encoding the IP addresses is also not a good idea. What if later on there comes a completely new IP address? You won't have a label for it.
I'm not sure about this topic, but I think you should scale your label-encoded input. But be aware that label encoding non-target data is generally not a good idea.

Next, the normal train-test split is not viable for time-series data. Training data should never be after test data on the time scale, and with a random train-test split, you get that. Take a look into sklearns [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html).

For the network, take a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446017) regarding the ReLU activation. While it is generally a good activation function, I'm not sure it'll work well with LSTM. You should test this. You also use your test data as validation and test data. Don't.

As for your data imbalance problem, look into undersampling/oversampling or weighting the classes (as done [here](https://nato16.medium.com/classify-the-imbalanced-time-series-data-with-rnn-8b51ad9222bc)). I think for time-series data you should look at the target class for under-oversampling.

Comment: the code has been updated,I've been working on this for couple months now  making adjustments ,took into consideration your advice if you have any other ideas please comment!

Comment: My question with "are you sure the packet data is time-dependent" still stands. Is the communication in one sequence coherent, and does it change protocol between communications?

Comment: The communication between 2 addresses is done using the same protocol
the same address can communicate with other address using a different protocol
the packet data should not be time dependent since it is network traffic of a data center